# Concept of toppling and rolling

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

Toppling occurs usually to blocks and caused by a torque. If we consider the motion of rolling, can we consider it to be a complicated form of toppling where the number of sides of the polygon tends to infinity? Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I personally think, the answer is yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. See the figures below.

You can think of the toppling of the block as rotation about a single point (in 2D) of contact of its leading edge in contact with a surface, which we can consider its pivot point. It the maximum possible static friction force between the block and the surface is not exceeded, the block will topple without sliding.

For a circular object, the point of the object in contact with the surface at any given time is the pivot point. The pivot point keeps changing as the object rolls along. You can think of it as constantly toppling over its constantly changing pivot point. If the maximum possible static friction force at its pivot point is not exceeded, it will continue to roll (topple) without sliding.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a sphere is a polygon with n sides where n approaches infinity. So when rolling a sphere you are making it topple infinite times. (I supposed by rolling you meant rolling a spherical object)